# UWP Custom Video Effect

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm developing an application for detecting motion within webcam frames.
For this, I'm using `IBasicVideoEffect` for extracting frames one by one from `MediaCapture`.  I have created class `CustomEffect` which inherits `IBasicVideoEffect`. I have used `OpenCV` for motion detection, it is working fine. It is also giving me motion detection level. I want to raise event from `CustomEffect` if motion level is greater than threshold.

But for videoDefination code is:

```
var videoDefinition = new VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(CustomEffect).ToString());
```

Here for `videoDefinition` constructor it is asking for `ClassID`,
How can i get event from `CustomEffect` object.
I want to raise custom event from `CustomEffect` (eg.: `MotionDetectedEvent` )

Here is my CustomEffect class:

```
public sealed class CustomEffect : IBasicVideoEffect
{
    private OpenCVHelper _helper;

    private IPropertySet _configuration;

    internal event EventHandler<EventArgs> MotionDetected;
    public void SetProperties(IPropertySet configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void SetEncodingProperties(VideoEncodingProperties encodingProperties,
        IDirect3DDevice device)
    {
    }

    private bool IsToDetectMotion
    {
        get
        {
            object val;
            if (_configuration != null &&
                _configuration.TryGetValue("IsToDetectMotion", out val))
                return (bool) val;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
    {
        var tempBitmap = context.OutputFrame.SoftwareBitmap;


        context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap.CopyTo(tempBitmap);
        var originalBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(tempBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight);

        var outputBitmap = new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            originalBitmap.PixelWidth, originalBitmap.PixelHeight,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Straight);


        if (!IsToDetectMotion)
        {
            context.InputFrame.SoftwareBitmap.CopyTo(context.OutputFrame.SoftwareBitmap);
            return;
        }

        if (_helper == null)
            _helper = new OpenCVHelper();

        var level = _helper.MotionDetector(tempBitmap, outputBitmap);

        RaiseMotionDetectedEvent();

        Debug.WriteLine(level.ToString());

        outputBitmap.CopyTo(context.OutputFrame.SoftwareBitmap);
    }
    private void RaiseMotionDetectedEvent()
    {
        if (MotionDetected != null)
            MotionDetected(this, new EventArgs());
    }


    public void Close(MediaEffectClosedReason reason)
    {
    }

    public void DiscardQueuedFrames()
    {
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get; }

    public IReadOnlyList<VideoEncodingProperties> SupportedEncodingProperties
    {
        get
        {
            var encodingProperties = new VideoEncodingProperties();
            encodingProperties.Subtype = "ARGB32";
            return new List<VideoEncodingProperties> {encodingProperties};

            // If the list is empty, the encoding type will be ARGB32.
            // return new List<VideoEncodingProperties>();
        }
    }

    public MediaMemoryTypes SupportedMemoryTypes { get; }
    public bool TimeIndependent { get; }
}
```

Comment: "How can i get event from `CustomEffect` object". What  "event" you mean here?  Could you please tell more details? Can't you create a `VideoEffectDefinition` instance?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I want to raise custom event from `CustomEffect` class. (eg.: `MotionDetectedEvent`)

Comment: I think you need to give some insight on the `CustomEffect` class, otherwise it will be difficult to suggest a solution. In general i would recommend passing a `AsyncCallback` object to `CustomEffect`. Please provide more details so that I can give you more details

Answer (score 0):

```
//in Windows Runtime Component

public sealed class FrameArgs
    {
        public FrameArgs(int frameCount)
        {
            FrameCount = frameCount;
        }

        public int FrameCount 
        { get; }
    }

public sealed partial class CustomEffect
    {
        #region ProcessFrameCompleted

        public EventHandler<Object> ProcessFrameCompleted
        {
            get
            {
                object val;
                if (configuration != null && configuration.TryGetValue(nameof(ProcessFrameCompleted), out val))
                {
                    return (EventHandler<Object>)val;
                }

                return null;
            }
        }

        public void RaiseProcessFrameCompleted(FrameArgs args)
        {
            ProcessFrameCompleted?.Invoke(null, (Object)args);
        }

        #endregion

        //call as necessary
        //RaiseProcessFrameCompleted(new FrameArgs(frameCount));
    }




//in your app
public static async Task<IMediaExtension> AddCustomEffect(MediaCapture mediaCapture, EventHandler<FrameArgs> callBack)
        {
            if (mediaCapture == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", nameof(mediaCapture));
            }

            var videoEffectDefinition = 
                // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
                new VideoEffectDefinition(typeof(CustomEffect).FullName);

            var videoEffect =
                await mediaCapture.AddVideoEffectAsync(videoEffectDefinition, MediaStreamType.VideoPreview);

            videoEffect.SetProperties(
                new PropertySet() 
                { 
                    { 
                        "ProcessFrameCompleted", 
                        new EventHandler<object>((sender, e) =>
                        {
                            var args = (FrameArgs)e;
                            int frameCount = args.FrameCount;

                            callBack?.Invoke(sender, args);
                        })
                    }
                });

            return videoEffect;
        }
```